# How to create custom list using widget in dojo worklight

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to use a custom widget to populate list items in worklight using dojo.I am not able to find a proper tutorial for the same.Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/). Especially the beginner tutorials. Then I would read the [Dojo Mobile Reference](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile.html#dojox-mobile) Documentation. Especially the [List section](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile.html#lists). For example, the [RoundRecList](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/RoundRectList.html#dojox-mobile-roundrectlist) provides example code.

I highly encourage you to take your time learning the platforms (Dojo, Worklight) instead of copy/pasting code bits without understanding what they do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question. Are you looking for an example to create dojox.mobile.ListItems programmatically?
If that's the case, you'll have to destroy all existing ListItems within the List at first. After that you'll have to create your new ListItems and append them to your List.

```
updateList : function(jsonArray) {
        // Query list Id and destroy all listitems
        var list = dijit.registry.byId(this.listId);
        list.destroyDescendants();
        // Iterate through JSON Array and create new ListItems
        for ( var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
            var title = jsonArray[i].title;
            // Create new ListItem
            var listElement = new ListItem({
                label : title       
            });
            // Append listItem at end of List
            list.addChild(listElement);
        }
},
```

You also should take a look into the documentation for dojox.mobile.ListItem, because there are a few more parameters than just "label" available.